# Wifi won't work on 14.04

Tags: wireless, 14.04, broadcom

I have tried to install B43 using cutter and STA wifi drivers for Ubuntu 14.04 on an HP Compaq nx6310, but it just won't work. Wired ethernet only works with the live CD. Any help on the exact procedure would be great. By doing the following below I get limited wired ethernet connection but no wifi! If I do an update after this I get nothing again.

```
cd /cdrom/pool/main/d/dkms
sudo dpkg -i dkms*

cd /cdrom/pool/main/f/fakeroot
sudo dpkg -i fakeroot*

cd /cdrom/pool/restricted/b/bcmwl
sudo dpkg -i bcmwl-kernel-source*
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Installing Broadcom Wireless Drivers](http://askubuntu.com/questions/55868/installing-broadcom-wireless-drivers)

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
sudo apt-get purge bcmwl-kernel-source broadcom-sta-common broadcom-sta-source
sudo apt-get install b43-fwcutter firmware-b43-installer
```

Comment: After this just have to restart and wifi is working!

Answer (score 0):

Install ndiswrapper

```
sudo install ndiswrapper-common ndiswrapper-modules-1.9 ndiswrapper-utils-1.9
```

Install the WiFi driver (from Windows):

```
sudo ndiswrapper -i yourdriver.inf
```

Check the driver is working:

```
sudo ndiswrapper -l
```

Load the module:

```
sudo depmod -a

sudo modprobe ndiswrapper
```

Configure modprobe so that it loads ndiswrapper:

```
sudo ndiswrapper -m
```

Edit the modules to add ndiswrapper at the end:

```
sudo gedit /etc/modules
```

Remember to add ndiswrapper at the end.

Hope you now have your WiFi up and working!

Comment: I am not using any microsoft windows on this laptop,must I create a  "ndiswrapper-utils-1.9 directory" first and then place the windows driver in it?

Comment: Please do what is in the accepted answer in the link below so we may see the information needed to help diagnose the issue.
<http://askubuntu.com/questions/425155/my-wireless-wifi-connection-does-not-work-what-can-i-do>

Answer (score 0):

I don't have an answer but this may or may not be able to help you. I used the following link https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WifiDocs/Driver/bcm43xx for my Wifi. I'm no Linux whiz it took me a while to figure out the exact steps to get my system working but that may not be the case for you. What helped me was the following:

- install the driver
- blacklist the other drivers
- load my driver automatically

The first two steps are mentioned in the documentation, the last step is not. I hope this helps you in any way.